# How to capture TPS for multiple system involved Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, tps

In my scenario, I have three systems A, B and C. I am creating load on System A and system A communicate in following way A -> B -> C. At last response comes to system A in following way A <- B <- C. I am being able to capture TPS via Jmeter for system A only. How can I capture TPS for the other two systems?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter knows nothing about the architecture of your application, it treats the system under test as the [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing)

If you want to check systems `B` and `C` performance you need to mimic the communication between `A` and `B` and vice versa in the JMeter test, the same for `B` and `C`. The approach is known as [Isolation Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Isolation_testing)

In case if for some reason it's not doable you can try to collect the information from the systems `B` and `C` using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) which supports a [variety of metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) and allows executing arbitrary commands/reading files in order to retrieve and plot the collected information.

Comment: I can not do it in isolation. I am already using Perfmon to collect system metrics for system B and C. Can you suggest which System metric is equivalent to Transaction per second or using which I can calculate the same.